# Order Processing and Preparing for Delivery happened at the same time

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

For few orders I am facing this problem..
Please help me to find the solution

Comment: I think you used onepagecheckout page right?

Comment: yes,onepage checkout

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to go with following path and disable paypal checkout option.

```
system->Config->IWD Extension(one page checkout)->Paypal Express LightBox ->  Enable Paypal Express Lightbox -> No 
and 
Sandbox -> No
```

If you have used another extension go with same instruction with your extension.

Comment: but here i am not using the IWD extension

Comment: I am using not any extension,simple default magento

Comment: ok. System->config->Advance->Advance->Mage_Paypal->Disable and also Mage_PaypalUk->Disable set this and check

Comment: clear cache and check

Comment: ok, let me try.

Comment: but i have to use payment method as paypal, if i disable paypal won't work

Comment: can you send me your site link?

Comment: site will not work on your system

Comment: you will reproduce this error on your server by following steps.

1. Place order. Click "Confirm Order", it will redirect to PayPal.
2. Click "Cancel and return", it will return to your site.
3. Click "Back" button on the browser, it will back to PayPal.
4. Complete the payment.

Comment: ok. i will try this and inform you as soon as.

Comment: did you find any solution for this  dude ?

Comment: can you send me your url?

Comment: its on local server, you can't able to access that

Comment: can you able to come on skepe?

Comment: i think the problem is with the ultimo theme,b'z i have repeat the same process in the default magento template, and its working

Comment: it's Possible. you can get theme provider support.

Comment: I used the same theme on other sites too,but not given any problem yr